# How to group by one field when the other field rows are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the result set i am looking for, but now i am trying to trouble the rows by Order ID, but i am having a hard time figuring out how to do this. The other fields for the duplicate Order ID are different so i am unsure how to group them, so it will only show one Order ID, even though the other fields are different. See below for the code and the output. When looking at the input just notice that there are Order ID's that are the same and i need to consolidate those into one row, even though the other fields are slightly different.

```
WITH CTE as(
    Select 
        [Order Details].[Order ID], 
        SUM(Quantity * [Rental(PLTR)1]) as [Sum of all ProductID]
    FROM [Order Details] 
    join Products ON [Order Details].[Product ID] = Products.[Product ID] AND 
        [Order Details].location = Products.location
    WHERE [Order Details].Location = 'OC'
    group by [Order Details].[Order ID]
)
SELECT 
    [Order Details].[Order ID], 
    [Order Details].[Product ID], 
    P.[Sum of all ProductID], 
    OrigSalesman, 
    Enterby, 
    Months, 
    Quantity
from [Order Details] 
join CTE as p on p.[Order ID] = [Order Details].[Order ID] 
join Orders ON Orders.[Order ID] = [Order Details].[Order ID] 
join [Job Name ID] ON [Orders].[Job Name ID] = [Job Name ID].[Job Name ID]
wHERE [Order Details].[Product ID] = '3367' 
order by [Order Details].[Order ID]
```

Here is the output:

```
Order ID / Product ID / Sum of all ProductID / OrigSalesman / Enterby / Months / Quantity

38119   3367    275 Susan DeMarchi  144 12  1
38119   3367    275 Susan DeMarchi  144 12  2
38119   3367    275 Susan DeMarchi  144 12  8
38119   3367    275 Susan DeMarchi  144 12  1
38301   3367    80  Susan DeMarchi  91  12  1
47476   3367    830 House Sale  25  6   1
47997   3367    0   House Sale  277 6   1
48760   3367    0   Don P. C. Carpentier    270 6   1
48761   3367    0   Don P. C. Carpentier    270 6   1
48762   3367    0   Don P. C. Carpentier    270 6   1
48763   3367    0   Don P. C. Carpentier    270 6   1
48880   3367    0   Roger Riley 270 12  1
51411   3367    0   House Sale  270 12  1
52444   3367    0   Susan DeMarchi  277 6   1
53280   3367    0   Roger Riley 25  6   1
59408   3367    90  Susan DeMarchi  25  6   1
59714   3367    75  Eddie Salti 453 1   13
60327   3367    1052    Susan DeMarchi  18  10  1
60394   3367    170 Susan DeMarchi  25  16  1
62687   3367    235 Susan DeMarchi  663 12  1
62776   3367    40  Susan DeMarchi  73  10  1
62876   3367    40  Susan DeMarchi  663 10  1
62894   3367    62.5    Susan DeMarchi  73  12  1
62898   3367    130 Susan DeMarchi  73  12  1
62915   3367    0   House Sale  270 6   1
62971   3367    84  Susan DeMarchi  663 12  1
62994   3367    363 Susan DeMarchi  663 14  1
62999   3367    75  Susan DeMarchi  663 12  1
63248   3367    62.5    Susan DeMarchi  663 12  1
63252   3367    130 Susan DeMarchi  663 12  1
63562   3367    0   House Sale  33  12  1
63894   3367    527.5   Susan DeMarchi  663 8   2
63975   3367    220 Susan DeMarchi  663 12  6
63982   3367    95  Susan DeMarchi  663 12  6
63984   3367    95  Susan DeMarchi  663 12  6
63985   3367    40  Susan DeMarchi  663 12  6
63986   3367    100 Susan DeMarchi  663 12  6
63987   3367    80  Susan DeMarchi  663 12  6
64269   3367    190 Susan DeMarchi  663 8   2
64269   3367    190 Susan DeMarchi  663 8   2
64643   3367    89  Susan DeMarchi  663 10  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Order Details` from the outer query and move filter by `Product ID` inside the CTE. That's it.